# Get data that PHP curl is sending

Tags: php, curl

PHP's curl is surprisingly undebugable and obscure. I have some problem downloading a JSON API data with cURL. I want to see what is exactly cURL sending to the remote HTTP server.

Currently the only debug option I have is to temporarily send request to some simple HTTP server that writes input to stdout. I would need to write that server just to debug curl!

What I do:

```
function get_data($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  echo "Download: $url.\n";
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  // I hoped to get some debug info
  // but this setting has no effect
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);    
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0',
    'X-Purpose: Counting downloads.'
  ));

  echo "Sending: \n".curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);

  var_dump($data);
  echo curl_error($ch)." ".curl_errno($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

How can I get the data that is sent by cURL as a text?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define the headers you should use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` and **not** `CURLOPT_HEADER`, i.e.:

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0',
    'X-Purpose: Counting downloads.'
  ));
```

To get the the content curl is sending use:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_STDERR,$f = fopen($verbosePath, "w+"));
```

---

```
function get_data($url) {
$verbosePath = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'verbose.txt';
echo "Saving verbose to: $verbosePath\n";
$handle=curl_init('http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0',
    'X-Purpose: Counting downloads.'
  ));
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_STDERR,$f = fopen($verbosePath, "w+"));
$data = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
fclose($f);
return $data;
}

get_data("https://www.google.com");
```

---

**verbose.txt**

```
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 80
*   Trying 172.217.0.100... * connected
* Connected to www.google.com (172.217.0.100) port 80
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
X-Purpose: Counting downloads.
```